# How to use ssh keys with Phing

Tags: phing, ssh-keys

When getting phing to use the SCP and SSH tasks, I currently have to enter my SSH password, but would like the tasks to use the key based authentication I have setup.

As far as I can see, the SCP and SSH tasks in phing need to be supplied with the public key file, private key file, *and* the passphrase.  Presumably I wouldn't want to hardcode my passphrase in my build file, so how do people use phing and ssh keys so that they don't have to enter the passphrase with every deploy?

And do I want to do this?  Or would it be better to leave it needing a passphrase with each deploy?

(I run phing while ssh'ed into my dev server, and am able to ssh from there to the live server, using agent forwarding back to my Win PC running pageant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ssh agent that stores the password for you for the current session.

Comment: So do you just leave out the passphrase parameter in your SCP and SSH tasks in your build file?  And it would ask for the passphrase, which ssh agent handles?

Comment: yep. you still need to register your ssh public key on the remote server (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) - otherwise the agent won't help you.

Comment: Are you using ScpTask, or just using exec to run the command line scp?  (When I use the phing ScpTask, I have to add the passphrase to the task, otherwise it fails.  I have added the key to ssh agent)

Comment: ssh-agent works using exec to run scp and ssh tasks.  I was just trying to use the built in tasks...